# Using PostMessage in Windows Mobile to simulate a menu pick

Tags: windows, windows-mobile, mfc, windows-ce, postmessage

I'm writing a routine to provide user definable keyboard short-cuts for any menu item in my Windows Mobile 5 application, which is in C++/MFC.  To do this I am getting all of the available menu command IDs, and using the CWnd::PostMessage(WM_COMMAND,MyMenuID) to post it to the application.  I use this technique to good effect elsewhere for inter-thread comms, but not with menu command IDs.  Any ideas why this doesn't work.  The app is document view, and I have tried posting to the CMainFrame and CView derived windows.  I could write a god awful switch statement but I feel posting a message should work.

Edit: Ok, i've tried a number of things, including suggestions from [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/02/542115.aspx), to no avail.  Big ugly switch statement it is for now, I'll update again if i find anything better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason I can think of is the message is going to the wrong window. Don't forget that not all menu commands are always processed by a particular window. Some menu commands like Cut are usually processed by a view window. Others are processed by frame windows and some possibly by the application object.

Hope this helps.